# 70s/80s SciFi film (or series episode?) where a spaceship has only one rescue capsule, so the crew members start killing each other

Tags: story-identification, movie, spaceship, b-movies

I'm looking for a movie that I once saw on German TV in the early 00s. At least I think it was a movie - I cannot say for sure that it wasn't an episode of some TV series. What ever the case, I'll try my best to describe what I can recall about it (spoilers ahead, obviously).

The film is set on a spaceship with a crew of roughly six to ten people. The ship needs to be evacuated, but no rescue mission is possible right now - maybe they are too far away from Earth, maybe their communication devices have failed, I don't remember. There is only one rescue capsule and it might be unclear whether the rest can be rescued at a later time.

Somehow, they determine who will go on the capsule. Maybe there's a logical reason for their choice, maybe they draw sticks - I don't remember. The lucky person is a 30-to-40-ish man who I imagine with a moustache when I try to recall his looks.

For some reason, the lucky person stays (has to stay?) on board a little longer. During that time, some crew members try to kill him, some try to convince him to let them go instead of him, some get killed in other ways (I guess).

In the end, the man with the presumed moustache is the only living person left on the ship when he finally enters the rescue capsule and the movie ends.

One particular scene I remember features a woman trying to seduce the man in order to convince him to let her use the rescue capsule. He plays along for a little while, but he doesn't fall for it and ultimately leaves saying something along the lines of "I will always remember you when I think of something very cheap!" ("Ich werde immer an dich denken, wenn ich an etwas ganz Billiges denke!" in German, if I remember correctly - maybe he says something different in the English version). I think the woman was Black and short-haired, but I'm not one hundred per cent sure with either of these properties.

I may have misremembered some of these things, so don't hesitate to suggest movies that do not match my description in all points.

The movie I am looking for is **not** among the following ones: [Trapped in Space (1995)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0108380/), [Lifepod (1993)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0107415/), [Lifepod (1981)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0125366)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This seems to be the *very* obscure sci-fi thriller [**Hyper Space**](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0249591/) (AKA *The Black Forest: Rage in Space*, AKA *Space Rangers*) from 1989. From [*Encyclopedia.com*](https://www.encyclopedia.com/arts/culture-magazines/hyper-space):

> **Six people awaken from cryogenic sleep to discover that their spaceship has become marooned lightyears from earth and only a single passenger shuttle is available to get someone home. Naturally, everyone wants that one chance.**

And you can see the line you quoted (or at least half of it) in the trailer, where a woman with short dark hair tries to seduce a man with a moustache who tells her in contempt (around 01:25): **"I'll always remember you..."** Here's the trailer, which is 90% people just punching one another (and as an added bonus, [here's the German version](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eB4HPAbxk5I)):

Comment: Thank you so much! I remembered it to look a lot more late-70s-ish, but that's definitely the movie - no doubt.

Answer (score 7):

There is *[Lifepod](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0107415/)*, a made-for-TV movie from 1993, an science fiction homage to Alfred Hitchcock's *[Lifeboat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lifeboat_(1944_film))*.  The timing fits, if it was being shown early this century; moreover, if I had to guess when *Lifepod* was made, based just on the visual appearance, I would say it looks like something from the 1980s.

The plot summary, per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lifepod):

> On Christmas Eve 2168 AD, a ship traveling through space suffers a critical malfunction.  Eight guests and crew escape to a lifepod, just before the spaceship explodes, killing all others on board.
>
> The survivors attempt to broadcast a distress signal and wait for rescue. As the days wear on, the lifepod suffers a series of setbacks and malfunctions: air and heat become limited, along with food and potable water. As supplies dwindle, the survivors debate whether, to conserve their supplies, they should prematurely end the life of a critically injured survivor who is consuming a disproportionate amount of supplies.
>
> One morning, the survivors wake up to discover their critically injured crewmate dead. The survivors realize there is a killer hiding among them on the lifepod. Eventually the survivors realize that its possible that one of the people in the Lifepod could have sabotaged the spacecraft, and who wouldn't balk at killing them to keep himself alive.

It does not match in every respect, particularly since all the major characters end up in the Lifepod.  However, once they are inside, there is intense competition for resources—to the point that at least one of the passengers is apparently willing to commit murder.  The cast includes a mustachioed [Rod Silver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ron_Silver) (who was the director as well as the star)  and [CCH Pounder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CCH_Pounder).

The whole thing is available on YouTube.

Comment: There was another movie called "Lifepod" in 1981. It seems to have the same plot.

Comment: That was my first thought as well, but if I recall correctly, the entire movie takes place on the lifeboat.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sadly, this is not the movie I'm looking for. It does look interesting, though. ;-)